# Extracting individual rows from dataframe

Tags: python

I am currently doing one of my final assignment and I have a CSV file with a few columns of different data.

Currently interested in extracting out a single column and converting the individual rows into a txt file.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv("AUS_NZ.csv")

print(df.head(10))

print(df["content"])

num_of_review = len(df["content"])

print(num_of_review)

for i in range (num_of_review):
    with open ("{}.txt".format(i),"a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(df["content"][i])
```

No issue with extracting out the individual rows. But when I examine the txt files that was extracted and look at the content, I noticed that it copied out the text (which is what I want) but it did so twice (which is not what I want).

Example:
"This is an example of what the dataframe have at that particular column which I want to convert to a txt file."

This is what was copied to the txt file:
"This is an example of what the dataframe have at that particular column which I want to convert to a txt file.This is an example of what the dataframe have at that particular column which I want to convert to a txt file."

Any advise on how to just copy the content once only?

Comment: You opened the file in "a" (append) mode. Then I guess you have executed your script twice, resulting in cumulate twice the string in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! While thinking about how to rectify this, I came to the same conclusion as you. I made a switch from "a" to "w" and it solved that issue.

Too used to append so I tried that before I tried write.

The correct code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv("AUS_NZ.csv")

print(df.head(10))

print(df["content"])

num_of_review = len(df["content"])

print(num_of_review)

for i in range (num_of_review):
    with open ("{}.txt".format(i),"w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(df["content"][i])
```